# WWDC 2009 iPhone Session Videos?

Tags: iphone

Has anyone bought these videos and if so are they worth the $299 price tag? 
I noticed that there is a lot of content here; is it worth it?

Comment: See my answer here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821769/how-to-access-apple-wwdc-material-of-past-years/7994301#7994301

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was at WWDC, and I can tell you that if you are serious about developing for the iPhone, buy these videos.  They are full of practical information, particularly in regards to the new iPhone OS 3.0 additions and OpenGL ES 2.0 on the iPhone 3GS (and now, new iPod touch).  The presenters are much more polished than you usually see at technical conferences.

For example, I wanted to implement custom copy-and-paste support in my application, so I watched the video and an hour and a half later I had everything working.  Were I to take the time to track down the right information online or in documentation, it would have taken me much longer than the simple "this is what you need to know" approach of the WWDC session.

The videos are nicely encoded to play on your iPhone (or iPod), so you can take them with you to watch on an airplane or while sitting outside.

If I'm not mistaken, you also get access to some sample code that was only made available to WWDC attendees and hasn't (yet) been posted online.  Overall, you get a lot of content for your money.

Comment: Do you know if the sample code ever got posted online?

Comment: Most of it has, but I think some of the examples are still only available with the videos.  A couple of the workshops at WWDC didn't even get their source code posted with the videos.

Comment: It seems that everyone can access the sample code now through here: http://developer.apple.com/wwdc/attendee/

Comment: Where can these videos be found nowadays?

Comment: @August - Unfortunately, they have been superseded by the WWDC 2010 videos.  I don't know of any place that you can legally obtain these online, but you could contact Apple's Developer Relations directly and see if they are still available through other means.  For a brief period, they were made free to all attendees of WWDC 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't at WWDC but I **did** buy the (whole) set, and basically... it's worth it.

I don't have $500 lying around just like that, but the vids are a pretty awesome / high quality and more importantly, a compact and content-packed resource of information regarding iPhone/Mac development which I'd otherwise spend on a couple books and *countless* hours of googling, asking, research etc etc.. and basically it allowed me to circumvent newbie-errors and give me a headstart in many areas I'd otherwise wouldn't have had.

Depending on how much your average hour is 'worth' professionally, these videos will pay of rather sooner than later, let alone the sample code.